# Search text in ActionText attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Post` model and this model uses ActionText for the attribute `content`:

```
has_rich_text :content
```

Now I have a simple search and I would like to search for text inside `content`, so I have something like this:

```
@posts = Post.joins("INNER JOIN action_text_rich_texts ON action_text_rich_texts.record_id = posts.id").where("action_text_rich_texts.content LIKE ?", "%#{search_text}%")
```

But this gives an error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column action_text_rich_texts.content does not exist
```

What is the correct way to search for text in an ActionText attribute?

Comment: Does Post model has content attribute?

Comment: No, that is handled by ActionText

Comment: Can you provide details of  Post model attributes and action_text_rich_texts model attributes.

Comment: It's simple, Post has a name attribute and a `has_rich_text` attribute for content. The whole content is handled by ActionText.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the migration generated by `rails action_text:install`:

```
# This migration comes from action_text (originally 20180528164100)
class CreateActionTextTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :action_text_rich_texts do |t|
      t.string     :name, null: false
      t.text       :body, size: :long
      t.references :record, null: false, polymorphic: true, index: false
      t.timestamps

      t.index [ :record_type, :record_id, :name ], name: "index_action_text_rich_texts_uniqueness", unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

It tells us that the contents is stored in `action_text_rich_texts` and that it uses a polymorphic association to link to the record.

So you need to provide both the type and id in the join as there can be multiple rows with the same id but for different models:

```
@posts = Post.joins("INNER JOIN action_text_rich_texts ON action_text_rich_texts.record_id = posts.id AND record_type = 'Post'")
```

You can just setup an association through so you don't have to join manually:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :content
  # used to query the attached ActionText directly
  has_one :action_text_rich_text,
    class_name: 'ActionText::RichText',
    as: :record
end
```

The whole query reads:

```
@posts = Post.joins(:action_text_rich_text)
             .where("action_text_rich_texts.body LIKE ?", "%#{search_text}%")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked. And also thanks for the comprehensive explanation, now I understand it better! I forgot the `record_type = 'Post'` part and I should use `action_text_rich_texts.body` instead of `action_text_rich_texts.content`.

Comment: it is very difficult to find active text related issues. You save my day! Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, Rails does this automatically now with the ```'has_rich_text'``` concern: https://medium.com/@dmccoy/rails-action-text-associations-and-eager-loading-77fd42a5c048

Comment: This did it for me.
I forgot to pluralize the `action_text_rich_texts` table call and kept seeing an `(Object doesn't support #inspect)`

Comment: I am using ransack and several has_rich_text. This line works like magic. So, I just added one action_rich_text_body_cont and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, Max, I have been struggling with this all day using Ransack.

So I added:

has_one :action_text_rich_text,
    class_name: 'ActionText::RichText',
    as: :record

And then used _or_action_text_rich_text_body_ in my search field and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :content
end
```

Rails automatically adds a `has_one` association [`rich_text_#{name}`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.1/actiontext/lib/action_text/attribute.rb#L53-L55):

```rb
>> Product.reflections["rich_text_content"]
=>
#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasOneReflection:0x00007f3a8071b1e8
 @active_record=
  Product(id: integer),
 @active_record_primary_key="id",
 @class_name="ActionText::RichText",
 @foreign_key="record_id",
 @inverse_name=:record,
 @name=:rich_text_content,
 @options={:class_name=>"ActionText::RichText", :as=>:record, :inverse_of=>:record, :autosave=>true, :dependent=>:destroy},
...
```

You can use it to join and search `action_text_rich_texts` table:

```
Product.joins(:rich_text_content)
  .where("action_text_rich_texts.body ILIKE ?", "%search something%")
```